# Migrar un proyecto de Android Studio a un ordenador Offline

Tags: android, android-studio

estoy tratando de migrar un proyecto de Android entre ordenadores sin conexión a internet. Actualmente trabajo con Android Studio 2.3.2, para realizar el intento de migrar el proyecto he copiado y pegado las carpetas .gradle, .android, .AndroidStudio2.3, la carpeta correspondiente al proyecto, la carpeta correspondiente a la versión del IDE AndroidStudio y la carpeta que corresponde a AndroidSdk.

Hasta aquí todo bien, el problema surge al iniciar el proyecto en el nuevo ordenador, todas las librerías externas desaparecen, además Android Studio me exige aumentar la versión del gradle de la 3.3 a como mínimo 4.1.

No entiendo porque las librerias se pierden y porque android de repente me pide actualizar la versión de gradle. Como no tengo manera de descargar automáticamente las librerías (En el equipo antiguo estaban en cache) he probado a importarlas como modulos, pero en cuanto solvento el problema de las librerias surgen otros cientos de errores de fallos de asignación en atributos y cosas similares.

Mi pregunta básicamente es si alguien conoce un método eficiente para migrar proyectos entre ordenadores que no disponen de conexión.

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Android Studio tiene una opción para exportar el proyecto en forma de `.zip`. Por qué no la usas?

Comment: La he usado, pero solo se exportan los ficheros propios de la aplicación y no las librerías marcadas como "librerías externas" que es precisamente lo que necesito exportar.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que poner tu Gradle en modo offline para que no vaya a buscar en internet, otra opción es tener las dependencias en formato .JAR para trabajar con ellas sin necesidad de resolver las dependencias.

Pero si necesitarías internet una vez por lo menos, sino tendrias que descargarte todas las dependencias de tu proyecto y modificar el archivo gradle para apuntar a los .JAR

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto se tendría que realizar pero después de bajar las dependencias, de otra forma no podría crear un projecto.

Comment: Hola, en primer lugar agradecer las respuestas. En el primer ordenador del que os hablaba la aplicación me compila perfectamente e incluso en este pc tengo la opción de conectarlo a internet, pero el progrblema surge al migrarlo al segundo pc ya que las librerías externas desaparecen, y no tengo manera alguna de conectarlo a internet ya que este esta en una red segura. ¿Alguna otra idea?